# NodeJS-Jade: displaying images in div from array

Tags: node.js, pug

I need to display image inside a div. Image URLs are stored in array. I need to pass this array to jade template and there I need to display them using loop. How to do this? This is how I am trying but it's not working.

```
- var arr = #{imageArray}
- for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
  <img src="arr[i]" />
```

The above gives Unexpected character '#' error.

```
- var arr = imageArray
- for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
  <img src="arr[i]" />
```

The above coe is not showing anything on web page. No error. As I am relatively new to this, I don't have much idea. Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Comment: did you try add the bracket

Comment: @HoàngĐăng I have updated my question.

Comment: and what if you try `ìmg(src=#{arr[1]})` ?

Comment: @mJehanno, in that case too I get Unexpected character '#' error.

Comment: I think it's a interpolation syntax error, try replacing `#` by `!` or like this `img(src=arr[i])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [each](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html) loop of Pug (Jade) to loop through an array:

```
each image in imageArray
  img(src=image, alt="")
```

Comment: it's called [pug, not jade](https://pugjs.org/api/migration-v2.html#project-rename)

Comment: yeah right, now it's called Pug. Thanks for correcting :) @PatrickRoberts

Comment: `src="#{image}"` should just be `src=image` in pug. Looks like you need to learn the new features in pug~

Comment: @PatrickRoberts No I think it's not a new feature. We can either use `src="#{image}"` OR `src= image`. Please note the space after the equal sign.

Comment: According to [this](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attribute-interpolation) you're wrong, and space is not necessary either.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Looks like I really need to learn the new features in pug :) . Thanks a lot for the info. Didn't check the latest syntax updates. Thanks again :)